# Can we get supported paper size of printer in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

Can we get supported paper size of printer in Actionscript 3? I read the help document of adobe PrintJob class but can not find the method to get the list of paper size of printer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`PrintJob.paperArea`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html#paperArea) to get paper size in points, then use [this table](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PaperSize.html) to convert width*height into readable paper format. According to the manual, this property is available before you actually start a print job, so it should suffice.